# Pointing to Cuda8 in presence of multiple Cuda installed

Tags: cuda

I have Cuda8, 9,10 in my AWS p2.xlarge gpu. it was pointed to cuda8.0 as shown in the nvcc – version and nvidia-smi.
yesterday i installed cuda11.0 and nvcc --version now showing 11 and nvidia-smi not showing anything. also i did not restarted my aws gpu.

Now i want to downgrade or point to cuda 8 again. what i have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple installations of CUDA in `/usr/local`, and the default version is determined by the link `cuda ->`.

```
xxx@cudap6:~$ ll /usr/local
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root   4096 lip  3 13:04 ./
drwxr-xr-x 16 root   root   4096 sty 28  2020 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 sie 26 18:02 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      8 lip  3 13:04 cuda -> cuda-9.1/
drwxr-xr-x 16 root   root   4096 cze 15 14:35 cuda-10.2/
drwxr-xr-x 17 root   root   4096 lip  5  2018 cuda-8.0/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 cze 24 15:24 cuda-9.0/
drwxr-xr-x 17 root   root   4096 lut 23  2019 cuda-9.1/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 sie  1  2017 etc/
..
```

Also, In `$PATH` I have entry: `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin`, which is the location of `nvcc`. It is described here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions

Comment: is the following are correct . ```  vi ~/.bashrc

export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-8.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH"


source ~/.bashrc  ```

Comment: you should not put LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your profile files. Also, I am not sure of CUDA_HOME is always necessary. I don't have it set up.Maybe only some libraries need it.

Comment: thanks a lot. so i will put only the following line.   export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}